# What is the best way to restrict jsonField's key value in Django model

Tags: python, django

I working on Django project for that I need a model to keep personalized_information from the user. This field is individual independent so I keep this as a JSON field. Now I am wondering what is the best possible way to restrict key values of this field.

Say some user would like to share name, address, email to us and some just want to share name. This list can increase from time to time. So its very hard to predict what is going to be needed in future. For simplicity, I like to keep this information as a JSON response in my database. What is the best design for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would use like this -

```
def validate_json(value):
    try:
        json.loads(value)
    except Exception:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an valid Json string'),
            params={'value': value},
        )


class Track(models.Model):
    personalized_information = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,  validators=[validate_json])
```